# timeout when connecting if streaming source is unavailable

Tags: timeout, streaming, handler, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to figure out a way of timing out a connection to my streaming http source if it becomes unavailable. I do have checks in place which verify if I'm connected to the internet, either WIFI or Data. I did find some example using a Handler and I got to the point where it actually times out, but it doesn't stop the actual service which is in a different class. This causes a ANR in emulator. Any suggestions or different approaches on how this issue can be handled? Thank you for your time !

```
public Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() { 
public void run() { 
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Running Thread", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (RadioService.isMusicActive()==false){
            stopPlaying();
            } 
        } 
     }; 

private void stopPlaying() {        
    buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    stopService(new Intent(this, RadioService.class));//
}  

if (v == buttonPlay) {                      
            startPlaying();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 5000);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing more with it and some minor modifications, this code worked the way I expected. Maybe it will help somebody else down the road.